# Where is Asp.Net Core 3 source code for ConfigureWebHostDefaults?

Tags: asp.net-core-3.0

In Asp.Net Core 3, in the program.cs, the `CreateHostBuilder` method looks like this:

```
     public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
```

A key aspect of this method is the call to `ConfigureWebHostDefaults` that sets up all the hosting defaults since in 3.0 a generic Host is used rather than a `WebHost` as was the case in 2.x.

I would like to review the code for `ConfigureWebHostDefaults` so that I can get a better understanding of what web hosting defaults are used for 3.0.  I've searched high and low on GitHub and can't seem to find the code.  Where is the code for `ConfigureWebHostDefaults` ?

I would also love to know what you searched on to find it, or what approach you used to find it?

Comment: ConfigureWebHostDefaults  Sets Kestrel server as the web server and configures it using the app's hosting configuration providers. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-3.1#host-configuration and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-3.1#additional-resources Hope that helps if anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/release/3.0/src/DefaultBuilder/src/GenericHostBuilderExtensions.cs

However, that's merely slim wrapper.  You really want:

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/release/3.0/src/DefaultBuilder/src/WebHost.cs#L208

Which, conveniently, holds the source for `CreateDefaultBuilder` as well:

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/release/3.0/src/DefaultBuilder/src/WebHost.cs#L155

I found this by simply cloning the repo, swapping to release/3.0 branch, running a search against the code base for "ConfigureWebHostDefaults", and so on.

Comment: links are D E D as a door nail! - https://github.com/aspnet/MetaPackages/tree/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/bb9653532ad5ce607d44dc4092cee899591e51f1/src/DefaultBuilder/src/GenericHostBuilderExtensions.cs